# Watson annotator for clinical data not working properly?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

The Watson annotator for clinical data is not returning the possible diagnoses, it's just returning what it is explicit in the text.

Example:

If i put all the symptoms of COVID-19, like, headache, cough, fever and tiredness, it should return COVID-19 as a possibility, but it only returns diagnosis(ICD-10) for each symptom headache, cough, fever and tiredness.

Another example, I put all the symptoms of lung cancer like, cough, chest pain, hortness of breath, hoarseness, bleeding through the respiratory tract, but it only return the diagnose(ICD-10) for the symptoms, it don't look at the general, only for the text that is explicit.

I've tried to tell a story about a patient, telling that he smokes since he was 14, and a lot more of information, thinking that it could help to watson give me the possible diagnoses, but nothing worked.

To make this tests, I'm using https://acd-try-it-out.mybluemix.net/preview. I've built a simple application with java, but the result was the same.

The documentation of this feature(cloud.ibm.com/docs/wh-acd) says that it analises all the information and gives clinical insights(https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/wh-acd?topic=wh-acd-clinical_insights_diagnosis), including diagnosis, but I don't know if I'm using it in the wrong way or if this feature really don't have this funcionallity.

Seems that they just need to add an "and" in the code, because now it's only using "or" to give the diagnosis.

One example of input and output using https://acd-try-it-out.mybluemix.net/preview:

Input:

"The patient is 55 years old, has cough and chest pain. He has smoked cigarettes since he was 15 and has never stopped. He began to experience shortness of breath and hoarseness in recent weeks. At the moment he has bleeding through the respiratory tract. An x-ray was performed and found the presence of lesions in the lung and white nodules."

The output:

[image]

Comment: Please add details to make it a programming-related question. What is the exact input and output. What is unexpected. Which parts of the documentation are you referring to?

Comment: One example of input:

"The patient is 55 years old, has cough and chest pain.

He has smoked cigarettes since he was 15 and has never stopped.

He began to experience shortness of breath and hoarseness in recent weeks.

At the moment he has bleeding through the respiratory tract.

An x-ray was performed and found the presence of lesions in the lung and white nodules."

Comment: I've studied all the documentation at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/wh-acd. The section telling about the diagnosis is https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/wh-acd?topic=wh-acd-clinical_insights_diagnosis.

To make the tests, I'm using https://acd-try-it-out.mybluemix.net/preview

Comment: the output you can see here: https://imgur.com/a/Wbw6Pdl

Comment: Add everything to the question, so that anyone who wants to help can directly get all required information from the question above. Remove what is unnecessary, add what is required to understand it

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik for the tips, it's my first question here.

Comment: I would suggest to open a support case. Based on your question above it is not clear what you are asking